# Css menu item group next to each other

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve this.

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>Full Time MBA</li>
  <li>Part Time MBA</li>
  <li>Executive MBA (EMBA)</li>
  <li>Senior Executive MBA (SEMBA)</li>
  <li>Master of Business Analytics</li>
  <li>Master of Management Programs</li>
  <li>Master of Internation Business </li>
  <li>Specialist Masters</li>
  <li>Research Higher Degrees</li>
  <li>Executive Education</li>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The following is my CSS

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  color:blue;
}
ul li:nth-child(n+6){
  float:left;
  margin-left:250px;
  margin-top:0px;
  color:green;
}
ul li:nth-last-child(-n+2){
  color:red;

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `column-count` property could help you :

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 60px;
  -moz-column-gap: 60px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 60px;
}
ul li {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Full Time MBA</li>
  <li>Part Time MBA</li>
  <li>Executive MBA (EMBA)</li>
  <li>Senior Executive MBA (SEMBA)</li>
  <li>Master of Business Analytics</li>
  <li>Master of Management Programs</li>
  <li>Master of Internation Business</li>
  <li>Specialist Masters</li>
  <li>Research Higher Degrees</li>
  <li>Executive Education</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Vote up for using column-count :)